# highslide close button doesn't work in ie

Tags: youtube, internet-explorer-9, highslide

Hi I have a problem and I can't find solution
If you know / used highslide script you know it's amazing, but as always f*****g IE has to make life more difficult.

Launch IE9 and go to page http://highslide.com/examples/youtube.html
Then try to open and close video, you will see that it won't close (ESC button works properly). You have to do it more than once. The problem appears only in IE9

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot and sorry for my english :)

Comment: Well, it's not just something odd about your IE9 configuration - I'm seeing exactly the same problem. It closes the first time, but if you re-open the expander, the close button no longer responds to a click. I don't know what the cause is. It's throwing a script error: '__flash__removeCallback' is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in IE9; the flash player throws an error, and unfortunately this JavaScript error somehow affects the Highslide close button the second time we tries to close the popup. Our developer has not been able to find why this error affects the Highslide close button.
You can however still close the popup with the ESC key.

A workaround for IE 9 is to add a message in the caption telling IE 9 users to use the ESC key to close the popup. Demo page: http://roadrash.no/hs-support/youtube-with-alternative-close-method-for-ie9.html
Add this code after the regular Highslide settings:

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
<script style="text/javascript">
    hs.captionText = 'Click the ESC key to close';
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.draggable-header .highslide-header ul {
    display: none;
}
.highslide-caption {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 11px !important;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i did it exacly in that way